# Matrix power without Numpy for 3x3 Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, wolfram-mathematica, exponential

I am trying to calculate Matrix raised to power 'n' without using Numpy for a 3x3 matrix (without using any library functions)

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
   def matmul(M1, M2):
        a1 = (M1[0][0]*M2[0][0]) + (M1[0][1] * M2[1][0]) + (M1[0][2] * M2[2][0])
        a2 = (M1[0][0]*M2[0][1]) + (M1[0][1] * M2[1][1]) + (M1[0][2] * M2[2][1])
        a3 = (M1[0][0]*M2[0][2]) + (M1[0][1] * M2[1][2]) + (M1[0][2] * M2[2][2])
        a4 = (M1[1][0]*M2[0][0]) + (M1[1][1] * M2[1][0]) + (M1[1][2] * M2[2][0])
        a5 = (M1[1][0]*M2[0][1]) + (M1[1][1] * M2[1][1]) + (M1[1][2] * M2[2][1])
        a6 = (M1[1][0]*M2[0][2]) + (M1[1][1] * M2[1][2]) + (M1[1][2] * M2[2][2])
        a7 = (M1[2][0]*M2[0][0]) + (M1[2][1] * M2[1][0]) + (M1[2][2] * M2[2][0])
        a8 = (M1[2][0]*M2[0][1]) + (M1[2][1] * M2[1][1]) + (M1[2][2] * M2[2][1])
        a9 = (M1[2][0]*M2[0][2]) + (M1[2][1] * M2[1][2]) + (M1[2][2] * M2[2][2])
        return [[a1, a2, a3], [a4, a5, a6], [a7, a8, a9]]
    def matpow(mat, p):
        if p == 1:
            return mat
        m2 = matpow(mat, p//2)
        if p%2 == 0:
            return matmul(m2, m2)
        else:
            return matmul(matmul(m2, m2), mat)
```

This works fine for smaller numbers of 'n', but it fails with the following error when applied to large numbers:

```
 File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 17, in matpow
    m2 = matpow(mat, p//2)
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 17, in matpow
    m2 = matpow(mat, p//2)
  [Previous line repeated 990 more times]
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 15, in matpow
    if p == 1:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Seems like it is reaching Recursion Stack depth when tried for large numbers, is there a way to implement power in an optimised way, without using libraries?

Comment: Can you add an example input to your question which triggers this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the power argument is really *huge*, then use an iterative solution, by iterating the binary bits of the power:

```
def matpow(mat, p):
    # Start with the identity matrix. This way it will also work for p==0
    # If you are using floats, then make this also with floats:
    result = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
    while p > 0:
        if p & 1:
            result = matmul(result, mat)
        mat = matmul(mat, mat)
        p >>= 1
    return result
```

Comment: This puts my solution to shame. Really nice approach

Comment: Thanks this is a great way! Did not occur to me

Answer (score 2):

When using recursion, the heap creates a new record in memory to store the return register, so that each time you call the function `matpow`, the program knows which register to return to when the condition is met. Therefore, instead of using recursion, I'd use iteration.

Use a while/for loop instead to iterate over until you find the correct value.

This should work (tested),

```
def matpow_iteratively(mat, p):
    new_mat = mat
    arr = []

    while p > 1:
        arr.append(p)
        p = p // 2

    index = len(arr) - 1
    while index >= 0:
        if arr[index] % 2 == 0:
            new_mat = matmul(new_mat, new_mat)
        else:
            new_mat = matmul(matmul(new_mat, new_mat), mat)
        index = index - 1

    return new_mat
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I like the approach used!